# How to iterate over an array multiple times without repeating summed elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to solve this problem but I don't know why I can't pass all test cases. I need some help and explanation, how can I count some array (in this example: variable s) multiple times and not repeat the same elements that I already summed.

Problem description:

> Lily has a chocolate bar that she wants to share it with Ron for his
> birthday. Each of the squares has an integer on it. She decides to
> share a contiguous segment of the bar selected such that the length of
> the segment matches Ron's birth month and the sum of the integers on
> the squares is equal to his birth day. You must determine how many
> ways she can divide the chocolate.
>
> Consider the chocolate bar as an array of squares, `s=[2,2,1,3,2]`.
> She wants to find segments summing to Ron's birth day, `d=4` with a
> length equalling his birth month, m=2. In this case, there are two
> segments meeting her criteria: `[2,2]` and `[1,3]`.
>
> Function Description
>
> Complete the birthday function in the editor below. It should return
> an integer denoting the number of ways Lily can divide the chocolate
> bar.
>
> birthday has the following parameter(s):
>
> **s:** an array of integers, the numbers on each of the squares of
> chocolate,
> **d:** an integer, Ron's birth day,   **m:** an integer, Ron's birth month

My code:

```
function birthday(s, d, m) {
    let bars = 0;

    if (m !== 1) {
        s.reduce((acc, val) => (acc+val) === d ? ++bars : bars)
    } else {
        bars = 1;
    }

    return bars;
}
```

Some cases:

- s = [2, 5, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1]
- d = 18
- m = 7
- s = [4, 5, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 5, 2, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3,
  5, 2, 1, 5, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 5]
- d = 18
- m = 6
- s = [4, 5, 4, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 5, 4]
- d = 15
- m = 4

My code works with this:

- s = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2]
- d = 3
- m = 2

This can be found on HackerRank > Practice > Algorithms > Implementation

Comment: Can I assume The s array cannot be sorted before adding Or we can sort before adding?

Comment: I guess It can be sorted. The point is to sum elements of s to be equal to d and, number of elements that are summed to d is m

Comment: From the problem description, it doesn't sound like you're allowed to sort the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to slice the array with the sliced length of `m`, and then compare that to `d`

As `slice` [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

> The **`slice()`** method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from `start` to `end` *(`end` not included)* where `start` and `end` represent the index of items in that array. The original array will not be modified.

For example:

```
s = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2]
m = 2 
d = 3

// We loop through s with index stop at s.length - m + 1 for slice to be in correct range

// Slices:
i=0: [1, 2] -> sum=3 -> res=0+1=1
i=1: [2, 1] -> sum=3 -> res=1+1=2
i=2: [1, 3] -> sum=4 -> do nothing
i=4: [3, 2] -> sum=5 -> do nothing
```

Below is a worked solution

```js
function birthday(s, d, m) {
  let res = 0
  const sum = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, el) => acc + el, 0)

  for (let i = 0; i < s.length - m + 1; i++) {
    if (sum(s.slice(i, i + m)) === d) {
      res++
    }
  }
  
  return res
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are looping over an array to get the summation or do a mathematical equation on it and you have to remove that specific element that you already calculated, You can use one of these built in function to remove an element from an array using a specific index.
[Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
&& [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy to understand way with nested loops:

```js
function birthday(s, d, m) {
    var matches = 0; // Total matches found

    // Look at chunks starting a position 0. Last chunk can't be m spots past end of array, so last chunk starts at 1 + s.length - m:
    for ( let i=0; i < 1 + s.length - m; i++ ) {
        var sum = 0; // What this chunk sums to

        // Sum up the values of this chunk:
        for ( let j=0; j < m; j++ ) {
            sum += s[i+j];
        }
        if ( sum === d ) { // Does this chunk sum to d?
            matches++; // Yes!
        }
    }

    return matches;
}
```